# Multipart upload of zip file to AWS Glacier freezes midway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, buffer, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to upload a 600mb .zip file to glacier using the multipartupload function of the node version of the aws-sdk. I figured out how to read the file as a buffer and start the upload using a script from the aws docs.

The script starts an upload for each part of the file but each one fails with a 400 error.

```
Uploading part 0 = bytes 0-2097151/*
Uploading part 2097152 = bytes 2097152-4194303/*
Uploading part 4194304 = bytes 4194304-6291455/*
Uploading part 6291456 = bytes 6291456-8388607/*
....
Uploading part 591396864 = bytes 591396864-591798963/*
//stops logging, then a couple seconds later, it starts returning an error message like this for each upload part:

{ [UnknownError: 400]
  message: '400',
  code: 'UnknownError',
  statusCode: 400,
  time: Tue Jan 10 2017 20:54:29 GMT-0500 (EST),
  requestId: 'F16FEDE011D3039A',
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 91.54012566432357 }
```

Below is the upload script I'm using

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var creds = <path to creds>
var fs =  require('fs');
var filePath = <path to file>;
var encoding = "utf8";

var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
  accessKeyId: creds.AccessKeyID,
  secretAccessKey: creds.SecretAccessKey,
  region: 'us-west-1'
});

var glacier = new AWS.Glacier(myConfig)

var buffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
// var buffer = new Buffer(2.5 * 1024 * 1024); // 2.5MB buffer
var partSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunks,
var numPartsLeft = Math.ceil(buffer.length / partSize);
var startTime = new Date();

var params = {
  accountId: '-',
  vaultName: <vault name>
  archiveDescription: '100media',
  partSize: partSize.toString(),
};

// Compute the complete SHA-256 tree hash so we can pass it
// to completeMultipartUpload request at the end
var treeHash = glacier.computeChecksums(buffer).treeHash;

// Initiate the multipart upload
console.log('Initiating upload to', params.vaultName);
glacier.initiateMultipartUpload(params, function (mpErr, multipart) {
    if (mpErr) { console.log('Error!', mpErr.stack); return; }
    console.log("Got upload ID", multipart.uploadId);

    // Grab each partSize chunk and upload it as a part
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += partSize) {
        var end = Math.min(i + partSize, buffer.length),
            partParams = {
                vaultName: params.vaultName,
                uploadId: multipart.uploadId,
                range: 'bytes ' + i + '-' + (end-1) + '/*',
                body: buffer.slice(i, end)
            };

        // Send a single part
        console.log('Uploading part', i, '=', partParams.range);
        glacier.uploadMultipartPart(partParams, function(multiErr, mData) {
            if (multiErr) return;
            console.log("Completed part", this.request.params.range);
            if (--numPartsLeft > 0) return; // complete only when all parts uploaded

            var doneParams = {
                vaultName: params.vaultName,
                uploadId: multipart.uploadId,
                archiveSize: buffer.length.toString(),
                checksum: treeHash // the computed tree hash
            };

            console.log("Completing upload...");
            glacier.completeMultipartUpload(doneParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("An error occurred while uploading the archive");
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    var delta = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
                    console.log('Completed upload in', delta, 'seconds');
                    console.log('Archive ID:', data.archiveId);
                    console.log('Checksum:  ', data.checksum);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Any thoughts on where the 400 errors are coming from would be greatly appreciated! I have not worked with buffers or binary data before so I might be messing up the format for this. The other suspect is that I am just formatting the glacier request or params wrong.

Comment: I'm not a JS guru but it looks like you're starting all of these parts asynchronously in a `for` loop, and you're trying to complete the upload as soon as the last part is complete... but with no guarantee that the other parts have actually finished.  Also, this means you will at some point have at least 600 MB of buffer allocated and 300 parallel HTTP requests running.  None of this explains the 400 error directly, but this seems a bit unstable to me.  Try with a small file, first?

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Let me rethink it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script that I created which tries a multipart upload one at a time. "Could try to be reworked to be concurrent but it works as is, retrying if an upload fails:

```
var minm = require('minimist');

var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var creds = <path to local json creds>
var fs =  require('fs');
var encoding = "utf8";
var partSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunks,
var startTime = new Date();
var byteIncrementer = 0;
var MBcounter = 0;
var multipart;

//move these out to args
var filePath = argv.filepath;
var vaultName = argv.vaultname 
var archiveDescription = argv.description

if (!filePath) {
    throw "ERROR: must pass file path via --filepath <filepath>"
}

if (!archiveDescription) {
    throw "ERROR: must pass description path via --description <description>"
}

var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
  accessKeyId: creds.AccessKeyID,
  secretAccessKey: creds.SecretAccessKey,
  region: <region>
});
var params = {
  accountId: '-',
  vaultName: vaultName,
  archiveDescription: archiveDescription,
  partSize: partSize.toString(),
};

var buffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
var numPartsLeft = Math.ceil(buffer.length / partSize);
var glacier = new AWS.Glacier(myConfig)
var treeHash = glacier.computeChecksums(buffer).treeHash;

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    glacier.initiateMultipartUpload(params, function (mpErr, multi) {
        if (mpErr) { console.log('Error!', mpErr.stack); return; }
        console.log("Got upload ID", multi.uploadId);
        multipart = multi
        resolve();
    });
}).then(function () {
    console.log("total upload size: ", buffer.length);
    recursivelyUploadPart(byteIncrementer)
}).catch(function (err) {console.log(err)});

function recursivelyUploadPart() {
    var end = Math.min(byteIncrementer + partSize, buffer.length);

    var partParams = {
        accountId: '-',
        uploadId: multipart.uploadId,
        vaultName: params.vaultName,
        range: 'bytes ' + byteIncrementer + '-' + (end-1) + '/*',
        body: buffer.slice(byteIncrementer, end)
    };

    console.log('Uploading part', byteIncrementer, '=', partParams.range);
    glacier.uploadMultipartPart(partParams, function(multiErr, mData) {
        if (multiErr) {
            console.log('part upload error: ', multiErr)
            console.log('retrying')
            return recursivelyUploadPart(byteIncrementer)
        } else {
            console.log("Completed part", this.request.params.range);

            if (--numPartsLeft > 0) {
                MBcounter++;
                console.log("MB Uploaded: ", MBcounter);
                byteIncrementer += partSize;
                console.log('recursing');
                return recursivelyUploadPart(byteIncrementer);
            } else {
                var doneParams = {
                    vaultName: params.vaultName,
                    uploadId: multipart.uploadId,
                    archiveSize: buffer.length.toString(),
                    checksum: treeHash // the computed tree hash
                };
                console.log("Completing upload...");
                glacier.completeMultipartUpload(doneParams, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("An error occurred while uploading the archive: ", err);
                    } else {
                        var delta = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
                        console.log('Completed upload in', delta, 'seconds');
                        console.log('Archive ID:', data.archiveId);
                        console.log('Checksum:  ', data.checksum);
                        console.log("==============================");
                        console.log('COMPLETED');
                        console.log("==============================");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

As mentioned in the comment, it looks like i was opening up a ton of http connections and trying to do everything concurrently which won't work.